# Can I book a flight on one passport and later change it to another passport?

Tags: passports, tickets, international-travel

I am looking to book an international flight. I presently have a valid US passport. I expect to be receiving another valid passport from a different country (due to dual citizenship) in a few weeks. To lock in the current flight price, can I book the flight on passport A, and then, once the other one arrives, change the information on the ticket to passport B?

Comment: Many airlines don't take passport details at the time of booking, while others give the option to save it early but don't require it until you actually check in.

Comment: Also it isn't necessary to fly every part of the ticket with the same passport, and in some cases the law even requires travelers to use different passports, in particular when using a round-trip ticket between the two countries of the traveler's dual nationality.  For example, an Australian and US dual citizen with a round trip ticket between those two countries will need to use one passport in one direction and the other in the other direction.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's perfectly fine. You can always present your new passport at check-in (where it matters).

Most airline requires that the name you use for booking matches the name on your passport so things can be a bit tricky if the names on both passports are different. In most cases the airlines can handle this as well.

It would be unrealistic for the airline to expect that everyone has the same passport at booking that they have at check-in. Booking and flying can be almost a year apart and passports often need to be renewed during this period anyway.

Comment: It's apparently even possible to have 2 passports from the same country?  I recall an episode of the UK show *Top Gear*, where they planned a trip through several countries in the Middle East, ending in Israel, which apparently doesn't allow people in if they have passports stamped from certain other countries in the region, so they had backup clean (also UK) passports for that crossing.  Not sure if that was technically legal though?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman That's legal, I even got the same advice when I travelled to Jordan.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Several of my colleagues have had two valid passports from the same country (Sweden). Getting an extra passport is possible if you need it for work travel or other special circumstances. The type of situation you describe with Israel and other Middle Eastern countries is explicitly given as an example of an admissible reason to get an extra passport. Other examples are if you need to travel with one passport while the other is sent away for a visa application or if you have no empty pages left in your passport but you still need to keep it because you have a valid visa in there.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, at least with the airlines I'm familiar with. If you want to be extra sure, call the airline.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is ok, but it depends on countries and airlines.

For the last point: some websites really sucks and they may add an additional fee (not small) if you check-in on airport (frequent on low-cost airlines), and good luck on low-costs to get customer support answers. So check online your airline reputation on doing such changes.

Countries: some countries requires API (advanced passenger information), and that should be given in advance. Usually few days before the flight should ok (else probably they asked you also a visa linked to new passport).

For travel there are always exceptions, but probably you know then if the flight is "special" (e.g. using military bases on scientific mission or just because it is the only way to reach such place).